# Discrete maths -

Tags: discrete-mathematics

i have read all , i try a lot with maths but now i am facing problem

$$
-3a_n + a_{n+1} = 2^n\\
a_0 = 0
$$

i have solve a lot but i could this,i want only the solution step step,nothing else. I have seen videos but i didn't managed to find similar to this.There are a lot but not like this

Comment: Find a recursive formula; for example, let $n=0$, then we have $-3a_{0}+a_{1}=2^{0}$ which implies $a_{1}=1$. Then find $a_{2}$ using this information and eventually you'll see a pattern you can use to solve for a formula for $a_{n}$

Comment: Google "use Z transform to solve difference equations"

Comment: i google this Z but the way is weird.even more i dont think it is like this

Comment: One solution (forgetting about $a_0 = 0$ for the moment) to an inhomogenous equation like this often looks a lot like the inhomogenous term itself. Try $a_n = x\cdot 2^n$ and see what $x$ might be.

Comment: One such solution (which doesn't satisfy $a_0$) is $a_n = -2^{n}$ (Just by inspection)
Proof:
$-3a_n + a_{n+1} = 3 \cdot 2^{n} - 2^{n+1} = 3 \cdot 2^{n} - 2 \cdot 2^{n} = 2^{n}$

Comment: You begin by "I have read all" : this is meaningless ! Please, next time, ask directly your question, without useless speech around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

$$-6a_{n} + 2a_{n+1} + 3a_{n+1} - a_{n+2} = 2\cdot 2^n - 2^{n+1} = 0$$

Hence you reduce the relation to:

$$a_{n+2} - 5a_{n+1} + 6a_n = 0$$

You can easily solve this by finding the charactersitic equation of it.

Comment: sorry for asking more,but how −6an+2an+1+3an+1−an+2=2⋅2n−2n+1=0 you think this ?

Comment: nonhomogeneous like this is the lesson called but this is amaizing you have wrote it.I may be begginer thats why i need more explanation

Comment: @user8543629 You have $-3a_n + a_{n+1} = 2^n$ and $-3a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} = 2^{n+1}$ from the relation. Now just multiply the first one by two and then subtract it from the second one to get the wanted relation

Comment: can i work on this ,if there is a similar exercise?an+1=an+2n for ao=0 . i cant do it up and down.the n+1 the first is down. The next n is down and the 2 the n near of it is up.Is the same this exercise like this?

Comment: i mean i can solve it with this way you saw me?

Comment: @user8543629 Did you mean $a_{n+1} = a_n + 2^n$? If yes, then you do exactly the same

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BG4x6 this i mean.

Comment: thanks a lot Mr.Stefan and the other guys who helped me <3 thanks really because i have searched a lot

Answer (score 2):

Let's write this as

$$a_{n+1} = 2^n + 3a_n$$

If you were to expand this for a certain $n$ you'd get:

$$a_n = 2^{n-1} + 3 (2^{n-2} + 3( 2^{n-3} + \dots))$$

If we distribute the factor $3$ we get:

$$a_n = 2^{n-1} + 3\cdot2^{n-2} + 3^2\cdot2^{n-3} + \dots$$

Or in other words:

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 3^{n-k}2^{k-1}$$

Which we can simplify:

$$a_n = \frac{3^n}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n 3^{-k}2^{k} = \frac{3^n}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^k $$

And now we can get rid of the sum because it's a geometric series, and simplify:

$$a_n = 3^n - 2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can prove directly by induction that
$$
a_n=3^n-2^n\,\,\,\text{ for all }n\ge 0.
$$

Comment: But finding the general form out of a nowhere isn't so easy, right? Anyway I guess the OP wants a systematic way of how to solve similar problems and not just something that applies to this particular one.

Comment: You are obviously right ;)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when solving linear induction relations you get solutions of the form $\sum \alpha_i(r_i)^n$.

Also the process of solving this has many connections with the process of solving ODE. Here for instance you can try to solve the homogeneous equation.

$-3a_n+a_{n+1}=0\iff a_{n+1}=3a_n\iff a_n=\alpha\, 3^n$.

Then find a particular solution of the full equation. You are guided in the sense that you can try sequences of the form $\beta\, 2^n$ according to my initial remark since here the RHS is an $r^n$, if that wasn't the case this won't work that well.

Here, the search leads to $-3\beta\ 2^n+\beta\ 2^{n+1}=2^n\ \beta(-3+2)=-\beta\ 2^n\implies \beta=-1$

Then you add the homogeneous solution and the particular solution to find $a_n=\alpha 3^n-2^n$ and finally the initial condition $a_0=0=\alpha-1\implies \alpha=1$.

And we get $a_n=3^n-2^n$.